# apache and nodejs proxy

Tags: node.js, apache, proxy

I want nodejs to work together with apache.

I try to edit the httpd of apache, like so

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin info@admin.bb
    ServerName www.myserver.net

    ProxyRequests off

   <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  <Location />
        ProxyPass http://localhost:8000/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8000/
   </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

I see the above method in many blogs and also here in SO. I saved, I restarted apache and I get

```
502 Proxy Error
Proxy Error

The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
 The proxy server could not handle the request GET /mysite/index.php.

Reason: Error reading from remote server
```

What is wrong with this method?

Excuse my ignorance, I dont know how to solve this.

Here is the part of node server, where I set a server...

```
"use strict";
var WebSocketServer = require('websocket').server;
var http = require('http');
var pg = require('pg');


var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Received request for ' + request.url);
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    response.end(clientHtml);
});
server.listen(8000, function() {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Server is listening on port 8000');
});

var wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
    httpServer: server,
    autoAcceptConnections: false
});

function originIsAllowed(origin) {
  return true;
}
//FALLBACKING FOR WEBSOCKETS
var pf = require('policyfile').createServer();
pf.listen( server, function(){
  console.log(':3 yay')
});
//STOPS HERE

wsServer.on('request', function(request) {
    if (!originIsAllowed(request.origin)) {
      request.reject(); 
      console.log((new Date()) + ' Connection from origin ' + request.origin + ' rejected.');
      return;
    }

//////////////


//prepare things to distinguish connections
var connections = {};
var connectionIDCounter = 0;
var connection = request.accept(null, request.origin);

// Store a reference to the connection using an incrementing ID
connection.id = connectionIDCounter ++;
connections[connection.id] = connection;

console.log((new Date()) + ' Connection accepted.');
```

Comment: You have an XML error in your Apache config: `<Location />` should be `<Location>`. That might be the source of your problems..

Answer (score 0):

> /mysite/index.php

You're asking NodeJS to serve PHP pages. It doesn't do that.

Comment: In that case I would expect node to deliver the PHP page as plain text - it shouldn't cause an error, though. Same happens when PHP is not installed with Apache - it would serve the source code.